# Trying to save configuration settings to a JSON file on a user's computer from the web browser using a React App that has webpack?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, fs

I am working on a social media app for a friend at their request which should allow them to create categories and then write hashtags that correspond to those categories. Afterwards they can just select them as opposed to spending the time typing them all out every single time.

Given the constant updating nature of the project I had set myself for a react web-app and thought I could store the categories and hashtags made in a .JSON file and then any time they added a new category / hashtag, I could just write to that .JSON file.

problem is, using "fs" gets me this error `Cannot find module "fs"` and the solutions about externals or target Node or other methods invariably results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` on the .JSX file that makes the reference to fs

I have linked my webpack below. I want to save to a .JSON file on the local computer's file system so I do not have to deal with/pay for some sort of online storage space. I do not want to use the download command because I do not want to open up that dialogue box and would rather have the file be written to a static location in the background. Likewise, I thought a webpage would be a good way to implement the app because when it is built they can just download from github and open the index.html in their preferred browser. If there is another alternative which is less of a headache I am all for listening to suggestions.

```
var path = require('path')
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.join(__dirname,'./index.js'),
  output:{
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer:{
    publicPath: '/build/',
    port:8080,
    hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [ new MiniCssExtractPlugin(), new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() ],
  
  module:{
    rules: [
      { 
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/preset-react']
          } 
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
  
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          //'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
        } 
    ]
  }
}
```

*edited for additional clarity*

Comment: re; architecture for persistence of user generated tags is likely to be a DB. If u dont want a db , you could store user tag list in cookies.  User on mult. devices wont have great experience however.  File system is just not the way to go in a web app environment. The build / bundle  ( webpack ) affects builds & testing more than it affects choice of architecture and choice of db or no db.

Comment: So you are saying I should try and use localStorage or cookies then. Guess the other option would be to go and package it to be stand alone with an electron app. 

I am not worried about experience on multiple devices. But good to know I wasn't missing something fundamental about javascript/webpack, this is just something that isn't done.